# Change datasource of ComboBox after another ComboBox value has changed

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am still pretty new to developing applications in Visual Studio (Recently converted over from MS Access) and I am writing my code in VB.net. My question is in reference to how to change a secondary combobox based upon the selection of another. All of my results are stored within separate SQL server database.

When my form is called the following will execute;

```
Public Sub New(ByVal _PartID As String)

    InitializeComponent() 'Required at the begining of calling a new form'

    LoadCombobox(cboArea, "SELECT [ID], [Name], [MRPShow] FROM [LocationArea] WHERE [MRPShow] = 1", "Name", "ID")

    cboArea.SelectedValue = 0
    cboBay.SelectedValue = 0

    LoadPartData(_PartID)

End Sub

Public Sub LoadCombobox(_cbo As ComboBox, _query As String, _displayMember As String, _valueMember As String)

    Dim SQL As New SQLControl

    _cbo.Items.Clear()

    SQL.ExecQuery(_query)

    If SQL.HasException(True) Then Exit Sub

    _cbo.DataSource = SQL.DBDT

    _cbo.DisplayMember = _displayMember
    _cbo.ValueMember = _valueMember

End Sub

Public Sub LoadPartData(_ID As String)

    Sql.AddParam("@ID", _ID)
    Sql.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM [Part] " &
                      "WHERE ID = @ID")

    If Sql.RecordCount < 1 Then
        MsgBox("No item found.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each r As DataRow In Sql.DBDT.Rows

        txtID.Text = r("ID").ToString()
        txtMRPID.Text = r("MRP_ID").ToString()
        txtPartName.Text = r("PartName").ToString()
        txtManufacturer.Text = r("Manufacturer").ToString()
        txtManufacturerPartNo.Text = r("PartNumber").ToString()

        cboVendor1.SelectedValue = r("Vendor1")
        txtWebsiteVendor1.Text = r("Vendor1Link").ToString()
        cboVendor2.SelectedValue = r("Vendor2")
        txtWebsiteVendor2.Text = r("Vendor2Link").ToString()
        cboVendor3.SelectedValue = r("Vendor3")
        txtWebsiteVendor3.Text = r("Vendor3Link").ToString()

        cboArea.SelectedValue = r("LocationArea")
        cboBay.SelectedValue = r("LocationBay")
        cboRack.SelectedValue = r("LocationRack")

        cboPartAssembly.SelectedValue = r("PartAssembly")
        txtDrawingNo.Text = r("DrawingNumber").ToString()
        txtImagePath.Text = r("Image").ToString()

    Next

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtWebsiteVendor3.Text) Then

        Process.Start(txtWebsiteVendor3.Text)

    End If

End Sub
```

Snippet from my SQLControl Class

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class SQLControl
    Private DBCon As New SqlConnection("---HIDDEN---")
    Private DBCmd As SqlCommand

    ' DB DATA
    Public DBDA As SqlDataAdapter
    Public DBDT As DataTable

    ' QUERY PARAMETERS
    Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)

    ' QUERY STATISTICS
    Public RecordCount As Integer
    Public Exception As String

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    ' ALLOW CONNECTION STRING OVERRIDE
    Public Sub New(ConnectionString As String)
        DBCon = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    End Sub

    ' EXECUTE QUERY SUB
    Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String, Optional ReturnID As Boolean = False)
        ' RESET QUERY STATS
        RecordCount = 0
        Exception = ""

        Try
            DBCon.Open()

            ' CREATE DB COMMAND
            DBCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, DBCon)

            ' LOAD PARAMS INTO DB COMMAND
            Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))

            ' CLEAR PARAM LIST
            Params.Clear()

            ' EXECUTE COMMAND & FILL DATASET
            DBDT = New DataTable
            DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)
            RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)

            If ReturnID = True Then

                Dim ReturnQuery As String = "SELECT @@IDENTITY As LastID;"
                DBCmd = New SqlCommand(ReturnQuery, DBCon)
                DBDT = New DataTable
                DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)
                RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            ' CAPTURE ERROR
            Exception = "ExecQuery Error: " & vbNewLine & ex.Message
        Finally
            ' CLOSE CONNECTION
            If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    ' ADD PARAMETERS
    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub

    ' ERROR CHECKING
    Public Function HasException(Optional Report As Boolean = False) As Boolean
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Exception) Then Return False
        If Report = True Then MsgBox(Exception, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Exception:")
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

So what I hope to achieve is when [cboArea] value is changed that the next combobox [cboBay] will be updated with the following;

```
Private Sub cboArea_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboArea.SelectedIndexChanged

    cboBay.SelectedValue = 0

    Try

        SQL.AddParam("@SelectedValueOfcboArea", cboArea.SelectedValue)
        SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT [ID], [Name], [LocationAreaID] FROM [LocationBay] WHERE [LocationAreaID] = @SelectedValueOfcboArea")

        If SQL.HasException(True) Then Exit Sub

        cboBay.DataSource = SQL.DBDT

        cboBay.DisplayMember = "Name"
        cboBay.ValueMember = "ID"

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

What I have above seems to be working correctly, however when I first open the form with a specific partID I receive the following error messages;

[image]
[image]

I believe these to be errors from the initialization code, where the part data is loaded into each control, thus calling the onValueChanged event, which keeps throwing the exception error, however I am struggling to identify how to resolve this, as I say the code works fine after the form has loaded and the user does their thing.

On a separate question, is what I am doing here regarding my data collection from my SQL database the best way to be doing it? I know most people follow this principle but I have also been taking a look into datasets and binding it to the controls, but I have not seen an article which states what style of implementation is better/faster?

Comment: When I run the code with a breakpoint the first Exception messagebox shown above is called when hitting the following line during opening the form "_cbo.DataSource = SQL.DBDT" within the LoadCombobox sub. This is not being called on any other combobox on the form. I also added a very simple "If cboArea.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then" before executing the SelectedIndexChanged event which seems to have resolved the second error shown.

Comment: Can we see the code for `SQL.ExecQuery()` and how `SQL.DBDT` is defined?

Comment: If you check the OP i have placed this snippet of code within the second code block "Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String, Optional ReturnID As Boolean = False)" I will update the block with the full code now.

Comment: I know the reason for that first error message but I can't provide an answer because it doesn't cover the rest. Please post a proper question, i.e. ask about a SPECIFIC issue and provide ONLY the information relevant to that issue. That means not posting loads of code too. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to separate your User Interface code from the database code. Your separation is very good except for a few message boxes you show from your `SqlControl`. This functionality should not be mixed in with your database code. Suppose the UI is changed to a web app. The reverse is also true. The UI should not be concerned with where the data is coming from. It could be a text file on there local computer of a web service on Mars.

I have made the Functions in `SQLContol` Shared which just means that the calling code does not need to create an explicit instance of the `SQLControl`. The class "shares" the same data with all instances. The only data the class has is the `ConStr` so this is fine.

Connections and Commands should be local to the method where they are used. Using...End Using blocks make sure that they are closed and disposed even if there is an error. .Dispose is important to allow connections to be returned to the connection pool and release unmanaged resource.

Parameters should include the `SqlDbType` and `Size` where applicable. See the following articles to understand why. http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Usually ID's are Integers. That is how I set up the code. You will have to change things if they are indeed strings.

You may have tried to get too generic too soon. Once you are more comfortable with SQL Server and vb.net, you may want to recombine some of the code to avoid duplication.

You did not show the use of the `@@Identity`. `ScopeIdentity` is a bit more restrictive in what it returns so you have a better chance of getting the value you expect. Unlike Access, Sql Server can execute more than one command in a single statement. I added a function to demonstrate.

I am sorry to say none of this is tested but I have done similar many times.

```vb
Public Class Form2
    PartID As Integer
    Public Sub New(ByVal _PartID As Integer)
        InitializeComponent() 'Required at the begining of calling a new form'            
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            cboArea.DataSource = SQLControl.GetAreaData
            cboArea.DisplayMember = "Name"
            cboArea.ValueMember = "ID"
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show($"Error filling Area drop down list. {vbCrLf}{ex.Message}")
        End Try
        LoadPartData(PartID)
    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadPartData(_ID As Integer)
        Dim dt As DataTable
        Try
            dt = SQLControl.GetPartByID(_ID)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        txtID.Text = dt(0)("ID").ToString()
        txtMRPID.Text = dt(0)("MRP_ID").ToString()
        txtPartName.Text = dt(0)("PartName").ToString()
        txtManufacturer.Text = dt(0)("Manufacturer").ToString()
        txtManufacturerPartNo.Text = dt(0)("PartNumber").ToString()
        cboVendor1.SelectedValue = dt(0)("Vendor1")
        txtWebsiteVendor1.Text = dt(0)("Vendor1Link").ToString()
        cboVendor2.SelectedValue = dt(0)("Vendor2")
        txtWebsiteVendor2.Text = dt(0)("Vendor2Link").ToString()
        cboVendor3.SelectedValue = dt(0)("Vendor3")
        txtWebsiteVendor3.Text = dt(0)("Vendor3Link").ToString()
        cboArea.SelectedValue = dt(0)("LocationArea")
        cboBay.SelectedValue = dt(0)("LocationBay")
        cboRack.SelectedValue = dt(0)("LocationRack")
        cboPartAssembly.SelectedValue = dt(0)("PartAssembly")
        txtDrawingNo.Text = dt(0)("DrawingNumber").ToString()
        txtImagePath.Text = dt(0)("Image").ToString()
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtWebsiteVendor3.Text) Then
            Process.Start(txtWebsiteVendor3.Text)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cboArea_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboArea.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim dt As DataTable
        Try
            dt = SQLControl.GetBayDataByArea(CInt(cboArea.SelectedValue))
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        cboBay.DataSource = dt
        cboBay.DisplayMember = "Name"
        cboBay.ValueMember = "ID"
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class SQLControl

    Private Shared ConStr As String = "Your connection string" 'Set from a secure location

    Public Shared Function GetPartByID(PartID As Integer) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Part] WHERE ID = @ID", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PartID
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetAreaData() As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT [ID], [Name], [MRPShow] FROM [LocationArea] WHERE [MRPShow] = 1", cn)
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetBayDataByArea(AreaID As Integer) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT [ID], [Name], [LocationAreaID] FROM [LocationBay] WHERE [LocationAreaID] = @AreaID", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@AreaID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = AreaID
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function

    Public Shared Function InsertData(Name As String, SomeInfo As String) As Integer
        Dim id As Integer
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
                cmd As New SqlCommand("Inset Into SomeTable (Name, SomeInfo) Values (@Name, @SomeInfo); Select SCOPE_IDENTITY;", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = Name
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SomeInfo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300).Value = SomeInfo
            cn.Open()
            id = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
        Return id
    End Function

End Class
```